# Boolean expression with only OR,NOT gates

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have the expression: x'y+xy'+y'z . I want to express this with only OR, NOT gates, but the issue is I have no idea how to remove the AND functions. I was thinking of using demorgans law, but I am unsure how and if it can be used on only part of the expression. Is there a way to simplify it and remove the ANDS?

Comment: Hint: Can you make an AND gate out of an OR gate and three NOT gates?

Comment: x'y+xy'+y'z === (x'y)+(xy')+(y'z). Now you can use De Morgan's laws inside each parathesis until all the ANDs are gone.

Comment: Oh I see. So (x'y) would be (x+y') correct? @Dampmaskin

Comment: The whole paranthesis also gets inverted. If De Morgan's laws are not clear to you, you should study them more closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: \$\overline{x}y+x\overline{y}+\overline{y}z\$, Turn this into NOT and OR gates only.

---

Just apply De Morgan's law on each of them individually.

Here's a refreshener:

\$\overline{AB}=\overline{A}+\overline{B}\$

\$\overline{A+B}=\bar{A}\bar{B}\$

\$\overline{\overline{A}}=A\$

---

First add some not gates.

\$\overline{\overline{\overline{x}y}}+\overline{\overline{x\overline{y}}}+\overline{\overline{\overline{y}z}}\$

Then De Morgan them to the maximum.

Here's the continuation in hidden format, I do encourage you to apply De Morgan's law on your own.

> \$\overline{\overline{\overline{x}}+\overline{y}}+\overline{\overline{x}+\overline{\overline{y}}}+\overline{\overline{\overline{y}}+\overline{z}}\$

And after you've applied De Morgan's Law, then you might want to remove unnecessary gates. Use these two yellow boxes as a way to control that you've calculated correctly.

> \$\overline{x+\overline{y}}+\overline{\overline{x}+y}+\overline{y+\overline{z}}\$

---

This is how it looks like in a schematic.

> [image: schematic]

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense. Now since the parenthesis have a complement, how would I go about making an AND gate? Wouldn't I need to have the complement somehow removed?

Comment: "*how would I go about making an AND gate?*", from what? And wasn't the OR + NOT gates the goal? - I am not following you.

Comment: sorry, misworded. I meant the or gate. How would I deal with the complement on the parenthesis since I need just the or gate

Comment: Are you talking about inverting the OR gate? \$\overline{x+y}=\$ NOT(OR(x,y)). - Just add a NOT gate at the output of the OR gate.

Comment: Oh I see, I originally thought I would have to use the not gate only for a single input, but I see this is not the case. Thank you!

Comment: @Kytex Added schematic for clarity.